# JavaScript Image. Browser save any image.src(). Javascript Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, html, image

I try to draw a lot of image in canvas.

```
var image = new Image();    
image.onload = function()
{
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
};
image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
```

Each new image saves in Resources->Frames->MyProjectName->Images. After a few minutes of work, my html page begins to take more memory.
How to clean unnecessary resources pictures?

Comment: depends on your image size....try to replace with an image of smaller size.

Comment: try to free up the image variable by putting `image=null;` at the end of the `.onload`

Comment: AFAIK - At best we can remove the image/canvas from the DOM, or try running this part of the code that handles the image data in an iframe/new window that we can close/reopen when needed. Maybe give some of the wider context for the app ( where are the base64Strings coming from etc )

Comment: How do you use this code with multiple images? Do you repeat that code for each image or is it in a loop? Show more code!

Comment: yes, i repeat this code with some Queue. It's very dynamic process.